# Multiple domains on single apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, multiple-domains

I have two domains but only one virtual server which runs a tomcat 7. I have my own ubuntu Linux with full root access running on the virtual server. I setup shorewall firewall which forwards any request on port 80 to port 8080 (where tomcat is listening on).

So I already searched the net but I only find "solution" that do not work in my case. This is what I did so far:

1. I copied my websiteA.war as ROOT.war into the $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ folder
2. I also copied my websiteB.war as WebsiteB.war into the $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ folder
3. I modified my $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml in the following way:

   Host name="www.websiteA.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"

   Host name="www.websiteB.de" appBase="webapps/websiteB" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"

   Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
4. I created the following file ROOT.xml in the folder "$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/www.websiteB.com" :

   ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?

   Context displayName="www.websiteB.com" docBase="" path=""

   /Context
5. Restarted tomcat. The websiteA.com gets deployed under "/" and websiteB.com gets deployed unter "/websiteB"
6. Entering www.websiteB.com arrives at "/" which means that websiteA is actually shown for websiteB.com

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey, did you get an answer to this?

Comment: Yeah, just updated this very old question with an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Goto your `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml` file.

There, you will find the following section:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    <!-- ... some other stuff ... -->
    <Host name="www.websiteA-Address" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
    <Host name="www.websiteB-Address" appBase="directory/of/WAR-files-for-B" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
    <Host name="websiteB-Address" appBase="directory/of/WAR-files-for-B" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
    <Host name="www.websiteC-Address"  appBase="directory/of/WAR-files-for-C" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
</Engine>
```

So, `appBase` will be the directory where your will have to put your `ROOT.war`(!) and `name` is the domain name that will be mapped onto this directory.

`directory/of/WAR-files` is a subdirectory in `$CATALINA_HOME`, that is the same **level**(!!!) as the standard folder `webapps`. So both directories coexist!